# How to set a variable inside an array in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to save some data from an included file:

```
class DATABASE_CONFIG {


    public $default = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'myserver',
        'login' => 'uname',
        'password' => $mysecretpwd,
        'database' => 'dbname',
        'prefix' => '',
        //'encoding' => 'utf8',
    );
```

But that's throwing this error:

```
Error: syntax error, unexpected '$mysecretpwd' (T_VARIABLE)
```

Please help.

Comment: Do you have `$mysecretpwd` defined somewhere?

Comment: yes im including it from a file.

Answer (score 3):

You can't assign variable in the definition of a class member variable. You have to do this inside the constructor. To access the variable, you should declare it global. Even better - you can pass it to the constructor

```
class DATABASE_CONFIG {

    public $default = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'myserver',
        'login' => 'uname',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => 'dbname',
        'prefix' => '',mysecretpwd
        //'encoding' => 'utf8',
    );

    public function __construct() {
       global $mysecretpwd;
       $this->default['password'] = $mysecretpwd;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Look at IdeOne. I tried to run your code and it works.

```
<?php

$mysecretpwd = 'my super secret password';

$default = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'myserver',
        'login' => 'uname',
        'password' => $mysecretpwd,
        'database' => 'dbname',
        'prefix' => '',
        //'encoding' => 'utf8',
);

echo $default['password'];
```

Follow [link](http://ideone.com/dDEPSp)

Comment: Still the same error.